# Why is my account closed to new questions?

Tags: support, post-ban

Why am I getting this message when I press "Ask Question":
You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

I have no idea what I would change in any of the questions I have asked.
I've tried deleting all my questions that were not answered.  No change.
What do I do next?

Comment: You mean specifically your [so] one? Given that you were able to ask here without a problem?

Comment: Yes, my question was about my Stack Overflow account.

Answer (score 4):

You have asked 15 questions, 10 of which have been deleted and none of which have any upvotes.

That's not a great track record. It shows that the questions are not of the quality we would like to see and the system has put the account into an automatic question ban.

This, as well as how to get out of the question ban is all explained in [the meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) linked from the message you get when trying to ask a question - it appears you have not read that or followed any of the advice within.

> I've tried deleting all my questions that were not answered

Had you read the post I've referred to (and linked), you would have found out that such actions are counter productive and only served to put the account deeper into the question ban.

---

Now, I've taken a deeper look, and the last question you asked was over a year ago.

Giving you the benefit of the doubt, and reminding you here that you are still very close to the automatic question ban (I suggest reading and following the guidelines of our [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help center article), I have given your account a small push out of the question ban.

Again - you need to ask good questions that are well received by the community if you don't want to drop back into the ban.

Comment: Can I have a small push out of the ban? I'm serious on the part about the ban.

Comment: Thanks for the response and taking the time to look at the details. This forum is weird.  I'm a moderator on two java forums and have been answering questions on several java forums for years; on one since 1999.

Comment: @NormR I've found the word "forum" is a taboo word around here. Despite the fact that it perfectly meets the definition of a forum, many will insist to their grave that it isn't one. I will agree that what they call forums are not what this is - this is a question and answer site. Ask questions, get answers. Discussion and discourse are not only discouraged but actively removed.

Comment: Got a 5 minute time out so I'll try to continue here. -- One set of questions about an Android project got so many downvotes that I deleted it. I suspect that most of the voters didn't understand the question. I've also asked general questions about how to do something, like what classes/methods to use and gotten dinged because I didn't post any code.  Thanks again, Norm

Comment: Have you read the help pages, particularly the information about the quality expectations?